# iphone - codification issue on the text visualization

Tags: ios, json, character-encoding

My app downloads info from a Mysql database. That info have a latin1_spanish_ci format. If that txt contains some caracters, for example  with accents, app crash.

In the downloading, I use a JSONdata format,

```
   NSArray* root = [(NSDictionary*)[datos_string1 JSONValue] objectForKey:@"locations"];
```

and a I define the NSStrin as:

```
NSString *info =[[root valueForKey:@"info"] objectAtIndex:i];
```

If any accent is present in the info, the  NSLOG give a  and the app crash when I try to visualize in a label.

I guess the problems regards codification. It is right? How could I solve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is description/class of Root object? Maybe [root valueForKey:@"info"] is not an array or this array dont have object at given index?

Comment: The array exists and tha app works propertly. But when 'info' string contains a caracter like ú á   (accents), the NSLOG of 'info' give back <null> and the app crashes